# Set the height of a div to the closest multiplication of X

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a bit of an unusual question (I'm not entirely sure how to word it), but I will do my best.

I'm trying to, using Javascript/jQuery, set the height of a div based on taking its current height (which is set by the text inside it) and then rounding it up to the closest multiple of 60.

For example, lets say the div is 192 pixels high, based on the text inside it. I would want the javascript to get this height, and alter the value to be 240 (4 x 60).

There might be an easy solution to this, but I can't think of where to start!

Thanks in advance, Harry.

Comment: I will just quietly leave this here: http://jsfiddle.net/hx7yehfr/

Comment: What's the actual problem? Getting the height? Setting the height? The math? All of these? Something else?

Comment: Hi Teemu, the problem I had was taking the initial height it's given and replacing it with itself rounded up to the nearest multiple of 60.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery:

```
var height = Math.ceil($('#thediv').height() / 60) * 60;
$('#thediv').css('height', height);
```

EDIT: For responsiveness, you need to reset the height before it does its calculation, ie:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    $('#thediv').css('height', 'auto');

    setTimeout(function() {
        var height = Math.ceil($('#thediv').height() / 60) * 60;
        $('#thediv').css('height', height);
    },1);

});
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the speedy reply. Have added this and it seems to work OK for the initial load, but I guess the next step is making it work responsively. The text goes smaller as it goes towards a mobile device, meaning the original height changes. Do you know how I could make this work? I have tried putting the function in a window.onresize but it seems to not work work as expected.

Comment: @HarryFrancis I have updated my answer with a solution for responsive designs

Comment: Great, thank you again, I will take a look at implementing this now. :)

Comment: Hi again, it seems to work very nicely, thankyou for your time and help.

Comment: @HarryFrancis Great, glad its working. Would you mind accepting my answer if its working, in case someone else comes along with a similar problem :)